# How to generate an insert script from a table with SQuirreL

Tags: client, squirrel-sql

I want to generate an insert script for a table. I don't know how to generate it from the table structure with SQuirreL as I do it with pgAdmin.

With pdAdmin I do this:

[image: pgAdmin INSERT Script]

Getting this result:
[image]

I have tables with a lot of columns(60) and I really don't want to write the script.

Hope exist a similiar option with SQuirreL

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same but, you can right click over a row of data and select 'Copy as SQL INSERT-VALUES statement'.